# how to validate java pojo int field with OVal framework

Tags: java, oval

I use `Java OVal` framework to validate my `java` bean, but one field of the bean is `int` type

`@NotEmpty` or `@NotNull` not work on it ,and I need to validate it not equal `0` which use simple `OVal` expression

Answer (score 1):

Primitive values can never be null. So a `@NotNull` check is always satisfied.

1. If the primitive field is considered valid in case the contained value is greater than `0` you can use the constraint [@Min(1)](http://oval.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/oval/constraint/Min.html).
2. If the primitive field is considered valid in case the contained value is anything except `0` you can use [@NotEqual('0')](http://oval.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/oval/constraint/NotEqual.html).

In case your field is not a primitive but a wrapper type, i.e. java.lang.Integer, then you also have to annotate the field with [@NotNull](http://oval.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/oval/constraint/NotNull.html).

You can find a list of all built-in constraints here: http://oval.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/oval/constraint/package-summary.html